# How to stop scroll up for <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit"/> in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I am currently working in a web application which has dojo in client side.Now for browser **IE11** I am facing a scrolling issue for the following component

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" name="favouriteList" value="favoriteList" onclick="buttonfix(this);"/>
```

The Problem I am facing is in some pages where scrolling is coming,when user scrolls down to button of the page(since the buttons are at button of the page)and clicks on the button,**no action is fired and the page scrolls up to the top.**.**To be noted this is happening only on first click on the button**.Now if user again scrolls to the bottom and places the cursor on button and clicks it then the corresponding action is getting fired.

From my First inspection I got the impression that dojo is probably the cause of this problem.Sop,I tried the following:
I removed the `dojoType="dijit.form.Button"` **attribute**.It resolved the issue.But unfortunately It is not acceptable since in our project we need to keep intact dojo.**Our dojo version is 2.1**.

The entire generated html for a particular button of my project is below:

```
       <button name="favouriteList" tabindex="0" class="dijitReset dijitStretch  dijitButtonContents" id="dijit_form_Button_9" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_9_label" type="submit" waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_9_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" value="favouriteList">
           <span class="dijitReset dijitInline" dojoattachpoint="iconNode">
              <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">
              </span>
           </span>
           <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_9_label" dojoattachpoint="containerNode">favouriteList</span>
       </button>
```

Below is the code for buttonfix(this) function:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function buttonfix(dojoButton) {  
            var button;
            if(dojoButton.id==""){
                button = dojoButton;
            } else {
                button=document.getElementById(dojoButton.id)
            }   
            for(j=0; j<button.form.elements.length; j++)
                if(button.form.elements[j].tagName == 'BUTTON' )
                    button.form.elements[j].disabled = true;
            button.disabled=false;
          }
      </script>
```

so,can anyone provide me any other solution to this???

Comment: try to change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. Do you want to submit the form or the onclick event to fire? Also it would be better if you can provide the entire HTML that is being generated.

Comment: yes I want to **submit** the form onclick.That it not occurring in **IE11** on first click instead the page scrolls up to top.Since I want to submit the page so I guess type="**submit** **"**  is appropriate.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do. You're saying that you want to submit the form, ok, but then why are you calling a `buttonfix()` function, which would clearly have no use because a form submit would trigger a page load.

Anyways, the scroll to top indicates that the page is probably reloaded because the form is submit (like Ted Nyberg mentioned in his answer).

Comment: Also, Dojo 2.1 does not exist as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but...

The scroll upwards is probably because the form is posted, triggering a reload of the page. Perhaps you could try changing your **onclick** to:

**onclick="buttonfix(this);return false"**

This would prevent the submit.

Comment: No.I cann't do it.As I mentioned in my post action is not triggering i.e form is not submitted on first time.I need to do post back.The problem is that on first click form is not getting post back instead the page is getting scroll up to top.

Comment: Ah, ok. What's happening in that buttonfix function? Does it work if you remove it?

Comment: I have tried by removing buttonfix still the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollOnFocus:false within the properties of the dojo button - https://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_form_Button_scrollOnFocus